# req.query is undefined in Next.js API route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to do a delete request. I can fetch the API route through `pages/api/people/[something].js`.

And this is the response I got from the browser's console.

> DELETE -  http://localhost:3000/api/people/6348053cad300ba679e8449c  -
> 500 (Internal Server Error)

`6348053cad300ba679e8449c` is from the GET request at the start of the app.

In the Next.js docs, for example, the API route `pages/api/post/[pid].js` has the following code:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const { pid } = req.query
  res.end(Post: ${pid})
}
```

Now, a request to `/api/post/abc` will respond with the text: `Post: abc.`

But from my API route `pages/api/people/[something].js`, `something` is undefined.

```
const { something } = req.query
```

UPDATED POST:

React component

```js
export default function DatabaseTableContent(props) {
  const id = props.item._id; // FROM A GET REQUEST

  const hide = useWindowSize(639);
  const [deletePeople] = useDeletePeopleMutation();

  async function deleteHandler() {
    await deletePeople(id);
  }
  return <Somecodes />;
}
```

apiSlice.js

```js
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  // reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: url }),
  tagTypes: ["People"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPeople: builder.query({
      query: (people_id) => `/api/people/${people_id}`,
      providesTags: ["People"],
    }),
    
    deletePeople: builder.mutation({
      query: (studentInfo) => ({
        url: `api/people/people-data/student-info/${studentInfo}`,
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json",
        },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["People"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetPeopleQuery,
  useDeletePeopleMutation,
} = apiSlice;
```

pages/api/people/people-data/student-info/[studentInfo].js

```js
import { ObjectId, MongoClient } from "mongodb";

async function handler(res, req) {
  const { studentInfo } = req.query; // the code stops here because "studentInfo" is undefined
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI.toString());
  const db = client.db("people-info");

  if (req.method === "DELETE") {
    try {
      const deleteData = await db
        .collection("student_info")
        .deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(studentInfo) });

      const result = await res.json(deleteData);
      client.close();
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: error });
    }
  }
}

export default handler;
```

Comment: These is no query parameter in this url `http://localhost:3000/api/people/6348053cad300ba679e8449c`

Comment: You can simply edit `res.end(Post: ${pid})` to `res.json({ Post: pid })` and `handler(res, req)` to `handler(req, res)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of params passed to your `handler` functions needs to be reversed.

For NextJS API routes the `req` is the first param passed to the handler and the `res` param is second.

Example `handler` function from NextJS documentation:

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly after I doing that. I'm laughing because I missed something that simple 